# Accessing YouTube Reporting in Automated Script

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, google-python-api, youtube-analytics-api

We're trying to write an *automated script* (i.e. no user interactions) that pulls YouTube reporting data from API (esp. with Google Python API Client).

Currently, we have a Google user that is a Content Manager of a channel, and we can access its Creator Studio on YouTube.

So far, we have followed the [official code sample](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/retrieve_reports.py#L53), created a client secret file for the Google Account, and we're able to access the reports after approving the permissions in a browser popup. However, since we are going to port it to an automated script, this is not practical for us.

Is there a way such that we can have a "client secret file" that allows us to talk directly to Google API *without* the need for extra verifications?

(*The [OAuth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) looks promising, as we're able to generate Refresh Token and Access Token there; however, we're not sure about how to use them in the Python API Client...*)

Comment: Have you tried accessing with a refresh token?